Buffering Issues with Reading a Stream-Written File in NodeJS
In trying to write to and then read from the same file, I've noticed that the below approach does not work, and I'd like to understand why (I suspect I'm missing some subtleties of async/await and stream constructs).  In running the code below, FileA is written to disk correctly, but readTextFile prints [''], as would be expected if FileA were empty.  It feels like the output of createTextFile() hasn't been flushed to disk by the time readTextFile() is called (I would have expected await to solve this).  The example works if I make the create function synchronous:
const fs = require("fs");
const FileA = 'testfile.txt';

const createTextFile = async () => {
   const rows = ['a','b','c','d'];
   const outstream = fs.createWriteStream(FileA, {flush: true, autoClose: true});
   for(el of rows){
      outstream.write(el+'\n');
   }
   outstream.end();
};

const readTextFile = () => {
   const clist = fs.readFileSync(FileA).toString().split("\n");
   console.log(clist);
};

const flow = async config => {
   await createTextFile();
   readTextFile();
};

flow();


Just because you mark function as async that does mean it will wait for all asynchronous tasks to be completed before returning. Your code is going to execute same as if createTextFile is normal function (ie: no difference between createTextFile() vs await createTextFile()) because in createTextFile you are not waiting for stream/file descriptor to end.
from docs

So solution is you have to wait for this end function's callback using promise API.
const fs = require('fs')
const FileA = 'testfile.txt'

const createTextFile = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    const outstream = fs.createWriteStream(FileA, { flush: true, autoClose: true })
    for (el of rows) {
      outstream.write(el + '\n')
    }
    outstream.end((err) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve()
    })
  })

const readTextFile = () => {
  const clist = fs.readFileSync(FileA).toString().split('\n')
  console.log(clist)
}

const flow = async (config) => {
  await createTextFile()
  readTextFile()
}

flow()



I think that also write method includes a callback, and there's a need to wrap it with a promise, too.

@RonKlein thats used when you need to ensure chunk is written/flushed to stream , which is different from OP's question. Its really bad idea to use here since write is being called inside for loop, so you end up wait for every write call which will slow down entire application.
